# What is Catalog and Mediaid in WindowsImageBackup?

Tags: windows, windows-backup, disk-image

I started backing up an image on an external HDD, and one thing I noticed is `Catalog` and `Mediaid`. I have some questions:

- What are these folders and files residing by my backup?
- What do they do/contain and what are they needed for?
- Can I safely delete them?

I tried searching first, but couldn't find anything. I looked further into the backup folder and found another thing named "esp" which I would like to know what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What is Catalog and MediaId?

> System Image backups use a similar folder structure to file backups. When you create a System Image backup, Windows creates a WindowsImageBackup folder in the root of the backup media. Within that folder, it creates a folder with the current computer's name. It then creates a Catalog folder containing the GlobalCatalog and BackupGlobalCatalog files and a "Backup -- " folder containing the disk image file.
>
> To back up an entire volume, System Image creates a .vhd disk image file, which is the same file format used by Virtual PC and Virtual Server. In fact, you can mount the .vhd files as secondary disks in either Virtual PC or Virtual Server, granting you quick access to individual files contained within the backup from a virtual computer. You cannot easily boot from a System Image .vhd file, however.
>
> System Image backups also create several other files:
>
> - A MediaId file in the  folder to identify the disk image
> - GlobalCatalog and BackupGlobalCatalog files in the Catalog folder to track the System Image backup image versions
> - Numerous XML files in the Backup folder, which contain configuration settings for the backup file

Source [System Image Backup Structure](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/system-image-backup-structure.html)

Comment: Oh and can you confirm whether all the partitions are in one big VHD or each partition has its own VHD? Because i see my computer backup and another VHD called "esp"

Comment: @NewbButLearnin Sorry, no idea. I only have one subdirectory which is my computer name containing Backup... and Catalog. Backup... only contains 1 vhd. I only backup my C drive.

Comment: Alright...Assuming you've backed up the EFI and files needed to boot, are they also with the VHD containing all files on c:/ or are they on a seperate VHD...I imagine ESP being the recovery drive i also included in my backup.

Comment: I don't have EFI and I have seperate recovery DVDs ... I have a recovery partition as well but I've no idea whether that is part of a system image backup.